# Interpretation of decay associated difference spetrum

Tags: spectroscopy, absorption, steady-state

We measured transient absorption spectra and we got
$\Delta A(\lambda,t)=A(\lambda,t)-A(\lambda,0)$. If we use DAS (decay associated spectra) for interpretation, we assume that our data have this dependance: $\sum_{i}A_i(\lambda)e^{-t/\tau_i}$, where $\tau_i$ is a lifetime of a component $i$. Decay associated spectra are then $A_i(\lambda)$. If we focus on one of the $i$ spectra ($A(\lambda)$), is there any easy way how to interpretate it? I am confused with mixing decacy associated spectra together with transient absorption.

Comment: "Is there an easy way to interpret it?" Yes. It's just the absorption spectrum associated with one of the reaction intermediates.

Comment: "I am confused with mixing decay associated spectra together with transient absorption." Transient absorption is an experimental technique (you measure the absorption spectrum over time as the reaction progresses). DAS is a modeling assumption: you assume the reaction intermediates all have first-order decay (as opposed to more complicated decay pathways). This assumption may not always be valid, and if so, you can get nonsensical values for the spectra $A_i$, indicating that a more complex model is needed; see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100710/what-is-decay-associated-spectra.